# How can I build the url string into dictionary and convert it back to query string

Tags: ruby

I want to modify url query string.

For example, the original url string is `http://book.fly.com/default.aspx?ao=B2CZHTW&dep=2015-07-16`

I want to convert it to hash like `{ao: B2CZHTW, dep:2015-07-16}`, just simply by pass in the url string

Then I might change some value in it. `{ao: B2CZHTW, dep:2010-07-16}`

and I can convert it url string easily.

like `http://book.fly.com/default.aspx?ao=B2CZHTW&dep=2010-07-16`

Comment: Are you using something like Rails, where you have this coming in through a request, or are you parsing URLs?

Answer (score 2):

To convert URL into Hash

```
CGI.parse(URI.parse(url).query) 
=>  {"name1" => ["value1"], "name2" => ["value1", "value2", ...] }
```

To convert Hash to URL

```
URI.encode_www_form("q" => "ruby", "lang" => "en")
=> "q=ruby&lang=en"
```

Comment: Hi I don't need the `[]` in the query string, `dep[]=2015-07-19` how could I get rid of it , thanks

Comment: Improved the answer. Hopefully it helps